# Jaxb2 generate classes with @XMLRootElement tag

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am using Jaxb2 plugin to generate JAVA class files from XSD files

**Here is my plugin config**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>parentA</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/test/resources/xsd/parent.xsd</source>
                </sources>
                <packageName>com.sample.generated</packageName>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**Here is my sample XSD file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.1"
           attributeFormDefault="qualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="../contracts/childc.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="../contracts/childa.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="../contracts/childb.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="parent">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:appinfo>
                                    <jaxb:class name="ParentA"/>
                                </xs:appinfo>
                <xs:documentation>Parent profile</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="birthPlace" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element ref="childA"/>
                <xs:element ref="childB"/>
                <xs:element ref="childC"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**I am specifying the name of the class file that needs to generated using following config in XSD file.**

```
<xs:appinfo>
   <jaxb:class name="ParentA"/>
</xs:appinfo>
```

**Here is am sample XML file I am trying to unMarshall**

```
<parentA>
    <name>SAM</name>
    <birthPlace>Dallas</birthPlace>
    <childA>..</childA>
    <childB>..</childB>
    <childC>...</childC>
</parentA>
```

**Here is the logic to un marshall Above XML**

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(parentA.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
parentA parentData = (parentA) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xml.getBinaryStream());
//Assert on parentData
```

- When I run jaxB2:XJC a Java file is generated with name as **"parentA"**
- But the generated file don't have the annotation **@XmlRootElement(name ="parentA")** at top of class.
- Because of which during un marshalling I am seeing an error.

**Question:**

- what additional config I need to add to XSD file so that the generated XML file will have @RootElement tag

Answer (score 1):

Removing the following in the XSD makes it works

```xml
<xs:appinfo>
   <jaxb:class name="ParentA"/>
</xs:appinfo>
```

You'll have the following class generated (but not with the desired name).

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "parent")
public class Parent
```

Since you declared the `xsd:element` with `parent` name, you should then try to unmarshal the following XML

```
<parent>
    <name>SAM</name>
    <birthPlace>Dallas</birthPlace>
    <childA>..</childA>
    <childB>..</childB>
    <childC>...</childC>
</parent>
```

Tested against the `org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-maven-plugin`, without the `childX` element (since reference in unprovided XSD), unmarshall / marshall was successful with XML `parent` tag name.

Output of marshalling : `context.createMarshaller().marshal(dto, System.out);`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parent><name>SAM</name><birthPlace>Dallas</birthPlace></parent>
```

If you still want `parentA` as tag name, you should change the name tag from `parent` to `parentA` in your XSD, the rest will still work like above with `parent` replaced by `parentA`.